# viewpager slow downs when paging in smaller sdk versions

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, android-support-library

I have to use a smaller version of sdk than 15 in my project, because my fonts crashes when using sdk:15, here is a screenshot:

[image]

But when I used lower sdk versions, my `ViewPager` in an other activity slow downs, here is my code for `ViewPager` activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private boolean async = false;

    private class MyFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            Bundle b = getArguments();
            final int position = b.getInt("position");

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);
            final ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);

            if (!async) {
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/image/"
                        + shortcuts[position] + ".jpg");
                img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                async = true;
            } else {
                AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {

                    Bitmap bmp;

                    @Override
                    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/image/"
                                + shortcuts[params[0]] + ".jpg");
                        publishProgress();

                        return null;
                    }

                };
                task.execute(position);
            }

            return v;
        }
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment f = new MyFragment();

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("position", position);
            f.setArguments(b);

            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return shortcuts.length;
        }
    }

    private int[] shortcuts = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        MyAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyAdapter(fm);
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    }
}
```

When I set `android:targetSdkVersion="15"` it runs nice, but when setting it to 10 the result is very slow. When changing the pages the result is slow, How can I fix it? My android-support-v4.jar file is 385,685  bytes.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No, I just changed my sdk version to a lower one.